# Info-path 2013 Multi line textbox is expanding unevenly

Tags: infopath, multiline-text-field

I am using SharePoint 2016 and InfoPath 2013. I am using Multline textboxes . When users are filling the text the multiline text box goes down with white space as shown in fig below. I tried to make it "Expand to show all text" but no use. When I keep "Automatically expand while typing" option its giving me problems while choosing printing the form. Can some one suggest what should be done to avoid that white space which I am getting.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues when I've tried to use multiline text boxes, so I try and avoid them. I've been able to resolve my format issues by switching the text boxes to rich text boxes rather than multiline ones. With rich text boxes you can wrap the text which helps alleviate a lot of the formatting issues that multiline boxes develop.

---

*Update*

**Before** adding text to the rich text box set to expand to show all text:

[image]

**After** adding text
[image]

***Make sure your text box is not inside a section or something that would cause that field to expand as your text box expands.***

Comment: Hi , I am seeing the same behavior with rich text box, can you suggest something

Comment: Did you set the field to wrap text? It's under rich text box properties-->display tab-->wrap text

Comment: Yes I did......

Comment: what kind of infopath form are you using? is it connected to a list or to a document library?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of what the form fields look like in infopath designer mode?

Comment: it is connected to library. I will post the screen shot shortly.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the properties and how it shows once text is entered in the field

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue while using a rich text box. However, I did notice that the area that says test still has a scroll bar. That shouldn't be happening with a rich text box set to expand to show all text.  Also, your text boxes should be blank if that is a screen shot from designer mode. So, it leads me to believe you're not actually using a text box or rich text box, but something else like a list box. I'm sorry, but I can't give any more assistance without more detailed information about your form.

Comment: In my screen shot I have shared the properties box as well, which indicates that I am using rich text box. Use a rich text box and set the property as expand to show all text , publish the form. now go and try to create new form and start typing in text and copy and paste number of lines and go to the next control you can see white space on the rich text box control which you entered the text.

Comment: Well, if that's a rich text box, it's not functioning correctly. You shouldn't see a scroll bar in the form if it's set to expand to show all text. That's not what mine looks like when I set the features that way and why I said I'm unable to reproduce your issue. I'll update my answer with screenshots of what my rich text box looks like with these settings both before and after I add text.

Comment: My rich text box is in section . Your answer says it should not be in section, but my functionality needs it to be in section. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Why do you need for it to be in a section? I just tested part of my form that I have a rich text box, with these same settings, within a section and it's functioning normally. There might be some wierd code that's stuck inside your design. You might try and make sure there's no white space between the text box and the end of the section. Then select both the section and text box field and select the reset formatting button to see if that helps.

Comment: Let me try to build it from scratch and I will update here.

Comment: I have created the form again and set the same settings but it is still same. I am asuming the culprit would be setting height of rich text box whihc might be causing the issue?